# Can someone help me with creating a list of sci-inventions?

Tags: technology, science-fiction, science-in-society, scientific-development

I'm trying to make a sci-fi RPG and I can't decide what technology I should use. Also all I can think of are overused cliques. I need some unique, really cool ideas. Can someone make a list for me of EVERY type of possible scientific invention that would exist in the future.

Comment: Welcome to the World Building stackexchange! Unfortunately this site is for direct Q&A, not idea generation or discussions, as so this request is not suited here. Consider reading the help center which details what can and cannot be asked: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help.

Comment: I agree with AngelPray about this question, so I'm voting to close it as 'too broad.'

Comment: [Your best friend](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SpeculativeFictionTropes)

Answer (score 2):

Google is your friend.   Start with Technovelogy.  Try having a disjoint set of technologies for each race.   That is, matter transportation in one race; size miniaturization/restoration in another; someone else gets wormholes or dark matter drives.   Decide how technology drives your story.  Are you writing *Diamond Age* (survey neat ideas), *RocheWorld* (explore hard sf), *Red Lightning* (one deus-ex-machina and follow where it goes), or *Warriors Apprentice* (human stories, in space)?